# Position of the title of the "table of content" differs from position of other titles

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, koma-script

I use Latex with the `scrbook` document class.

I noticed that the title *Table of Content* has a different position than e.g. *Table of Figures* or *Chapter 1*.
It actually is placed a bit lower.
(I mean the absolute position on the page)

I wonder if this is a "bug" and how it could be corrected.

**PROBLEM REMAINS**

The answer below was/is very helpful!
I carefully expanded the MWE and kinda found the problem:

I added some options to the scrbook package
and found that these produce the described behaviour.
(My first edit with scrpage2 was incorrect.)

```
\documentclass[headsepline,
               footsepline,
               parskip=half
               ]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure one}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]\caption{Table one}\end{table}
\section{Section 1}
Text
\section{Section 2}
Text
\section{Section 3}
Text
\section{Section 4}
Text
\section{Section 5}
Text

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure two}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]\caption{Table two}\end{table}

\chapter{Chapter Number 3}
\section{Section 1}
Text
\section{Section 2}
Text
\section{Section 3}
Text
\section{Section 4}
Text
\section{Section 5}
Text

\chapter{Chapter Number 4}
\section{Section 1}
Text
\section{Section 2}
Text
\section{Section 3}
Text
\section{Section 4}
Text
\section{Section 5}
Text

\chapter{Chapter Number 5}
\section{Section 1}
Text
\section{Section 2}
Text
\section{Section 3}
Text
\section{Section 4}
Text
\section{Section 5}
Text

\chapter{Chapter Number 6}
\chapter{Chapter Number 7}
\chapter{Chapter Number 8}
\chapter{Chapter Number 9}

\chapter{Last chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure three}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]\caption{Table onthreee}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your answer was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or edit your answer. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I can confirm the existence of the problem. It happened with my thesis. I however just ignored it at this stage.

Comment: The requested MWE (thx @Marco Daniel) narrowed the problem to scrbook options.

Answer (score 5):

This should not be the case, since all of the contents-related production is performed using the same sectioning commands in the rest of the document. For example, `\tableofcontents` issues a `\chapter*{Contents}`, which is at the same height from the text block and page boundary than regular `\chapter` and `\chapter*` commands.

The following MWE shows this (with only the relevant pages cut out):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure one}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]\caption{Table one}\end{table}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure two}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]\caption{Table two}\end{table}
\chapter{Last chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure three}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]\caption{Table onthreee}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Unless, of course, if you do something different in terms of the formatting of the ToC compared to other elements.

Comment: Still, it happens, I have seen that before, however, I doubt I can reproduce it now.